# Getting size information on object with index signature

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript class with an index signature, like so:

```
[index: number]: {
   start: number;
   length: number;
}
```

I would like to get information on the number of items it holds. I haven't found a good way to do so, because using `Object.keys(myObject).length` to get the length works, but is very error prone, because the day I add a member to my class, that value becomes wrong.

Comment: Not sure why `for (ley key in obj) { obj[key] }` or  `for (ley key of Object.keys(myObject)){ obj[key] }` won't work. Could you post the actual code you tried and doe snot work ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks for the reply ! Sorry, I don't know what happened when I wrote that question, what I was looking for was not iteration, but getting information on the number of elements in the object. I have edited my answer to reflect it